# REST::Client: how to ignore SSL certificates

Tags: perl

I am working with `REST::Client` and my code fails with SSL error.

Here is the code:

```
#!usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use REST::Client;

my $client = REST::Client->new();

$client->GET("https://something/api/sessions");
print $client->responseContent();
```

and here is the output:

```
WP::Protocol::https::Socket: SSL connect attempt failed with unknown error error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 51.
```

I know the problem. `REST::Client` is not able to ignore the SSL certificate.

I get the exact same error with `curl` when I do not use "-k" option:

here is curl command:

```
curl -i -H "Accept:application/*+xml;version=1.5" -u "username@system:password" -X post https://something/api/sessions
```

and here is curl output(Error):

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

However, if I add "-k" to the curl command, then it works just fine.

From curl's man page, here is the explanation of "-k":

```
(SSL)  This  option  explicitly  allows  curl to perform "insecure" SSL connections and transfers.
```

**Question:**

So, How do I make `REST::Client` ignore the SSL certificate? OR is there any other elegant way to work with? I gone through the `REST::Client` documentation on CPAN but it does not talk anything about this.

Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth it is *far* better to deploy a proper CA signed cert to the service (if possible) or, only if the cert is unique, specifically trust the individual cert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working by adding below line:

```
$ENV{PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME}=0;
```

Reference: https://splash.riverbed.com/docs/DOC-1602

Answer (score 4):

I found that option did not completely address the issue in LWP 6.x.  For me this worked:

```
# setup rest client                                                                                                             
my $client = REST::Client->new();                                                                                               

# don't verify SSL certs                                                                                                        
$client->getUseragent()->ssl_opts(verify_hostname => 0);                                                                        
$client->getUseragent()->ssl_opts(SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE);
```

Comment: Works great. Only SSL_VERIFY_NONE needs to be encapsulated in single quotes to prevent strict compile failure.

Comment: Usuallly keys on the left side of `=>` are implicitly quoted in Perl.  I haven't had this trip up `strict`ness which I usually have on.  That's why the code sample includes the `my`.